# Can't afford a cell phone, just home line, so how do I create a Gmail account?

Tags: gmail

I have Acquired Brain Injury (ABI) and so cannot afford a cell phone. I keep up my home-line payments in case 911 emergencies. (The laptop is a gift my son.) When I try to create a new Gmail account, verification codes are sent to my non-existent cell number. Is there some way to verify via my home line? O/S is Windows 10.
Laptop is Lenovo Flex 14. Intel Core i5-8250U CPU @ 1.6 GHz 1.8 GHz

Comment: It is not necessary to use a cell phone number. You need to set up an account without 3 step verification which includes a cell phone number

Answer (score 1):

There is a field labelled "not now" on the page where Google says they will call you.  Click on it. When I did,  Google let me create an account.

There is google voice.  Create an account and google will send you a message when you get a call.